# Computing $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(i+1)(i+2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

one method is to expand $n(n+1)(n+2)$ and sum over that, but the answer I note is

> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i(i+1)(i+2)=\frac{1}{4}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$$

points to an alternate, elegant solution.

Comment: The very form of the final solution suggests telescoping. Rewrite each term as the difference of two terms in that form.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "till $n$" but in any case your sum is something like $\sum_{i=1}^n i(i+1)(i+2)$ and you can expand that into a sum of terms like $A\sum i + B\sum i^2+ C\sum i^3$ and use standard formulas.

Comment: @lulu I meant sum till the nth term is of form n(n+1)(n+2). But yeah, expanding is exactly what I don't want to do because there looks to be a nice solution to this

Comment: Writing your sum as $6+\sum_{i=-3}^ni(i+1)(i+2)$, it's not hard to prove that it must be a degree-four polynomial with roots at $n=0,-1,-2,-3$ (this is the reason for the strange indexing). From there we really only need to calculate a single value non-zero value to get the coefficient $\frac14$.

Comment: btw can anyone tell me why I'm downvoted?

Comment: @Vrisk Downvoting here is sometimes arbitrary, and there is, unfortunately, no prompt to comment when you downvote. So there are lots of downvotes without an accompanying explanation on this site. It could be your lack of math formatting. It could be that they thought your post was too brief with not enough of your own thoughts and results. It could be something entirely different.

Comment: @arthur, that solution is really neat but wouldn't 0,-1,-2,-3 be the roots of 6 + desired sum? So I'd have to subtract 6 and that'd mess things up?

Comment: @Vrisk Did you actually try and see what happens? Insert $n=-3$ or $n=0$ and see what you get.

Comment: @arthur, thanks, I got it. You the thing will be of from k(n-1)(n-2)(n-3) + c, where you'll simply get c = 6 by substitution so that six which you moved disappears. Cool stuff, man.

Comment: @Vrisk I don't like discussing in chat, so I'm going to decline. Inserting $n=-3$ ought to give $6+(-3)(-2)(-1)=6-6=0$, and for $n=-2,-1$ and $0$ you get the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, \begin{align*}\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)(k+2)&=6\sum_{k=1}^{n}{k+2\choose 3}=6\sum_{k=3}^{n+2}{k\choose 3}=6\sum_{k=1}^{n+2}{k\choose 3}\end{align*} and using the [following theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_k_Choose_m_up_to_n), we get $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1)(k+2)=6{n+3\choose 4}=6\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}{4!}$$

---

The above method suggests that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k(k+1){\dots}(k+m)=\frac{1}{m+2}n(n+1){\dots}(n+m+1)$$

Comment: I don't get the theorem, how do you get the top of the choose to be greater than the bottom ie $^1C_m$ where m> 1

Comment: For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t $n<m$ we have $^nC_m=0$.

Answer (score 2):

In general: $$\sum_{k=r}^n\binom{k}{r}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}\tag1$$ This can easily be proved with induction on $n$ using the well known equality: $$\binom{n+1}r+\binom{n+1}{r+1}=\binom{n+2}{r+1}$$

Applying $(1)$ for $r=3$ we find: $$\frac1{3!}\sum_{k=3}^n(k-2)(k-1)k=\frac1{4!}(n-2)(n-1)n(n+1)$$

Taking $n+2$ instead of $n$ and $i$ instead of $k$ gives:$$\sum_{i=1}^ni(i+1)(i+2)=\frac1{4}n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)$$